# Using socket.io and node for backend. What does this.emit means here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I came across this code when I am working on a project. I am not able to understand why 'this' is used in the createNewGame method?  Btw I am using socket.io and express js for my project.

```
var io
var gameSocket
var gamesInSession = []

const initializeGame = (sio, socket) => {
    // initialize global variables.
    io = sio 
    gameSocket = socket 

    gamesInSession.push(gameSocket)

    // User creates new game room after clicking 'submit' on the frontend
    gameSocket.on("createNewGame", createNewGame);

    ...

}

function createNewGame(gameId) {

    // Return the Room ID (gameId) and the socket ID (mySocketId) to the browser client

    this.emit('createNewGame', {gameId: gameId, mySocketId: this.id});  //What does this refer too here?


    this.join(gameId)
}
```

Comment: you can "console.log(this)", to see what it is

Comment: `mySocketId: this.id` — the name of the property the value is being copied too might be a clue

Comment: I log and it is giving me something like this:
Socket {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    createNewGame: [Function: createNewGame],
  },